# Getting the value of a particular cell with AJAX

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ajax

My goal is very simple and I would guess it is a very common goal among web developers.

I am creating a Rails (5.1) application, and I simply want to use AJAX to get the value of a specific cell in a specific row of a specific table in my database (later I am going to use that value to highlight some text on the current page in the user's browser).

I have not been able to find any documentation online explaining how to do this. As I said, it seems like a basic task to ask of jquery and ajax, so I'm confused as to why I'm having so much trouble figuring it out.

For concreteness, say I have a table called 'animals', and I want to get the value of the column 'species' for the animal with 'id' = 99.

How can I construct an AJAX call to query the database for the value of 'species' for the 'animal' with 'id' = 99 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though some DBs provide a REST API, what we commonly do is define a route in the app to pull and return data from the DB.

So:

1. Add a route
2. Add a controller/action for that route
3. In that action, fetch the data from the DB and render it in your preferred format
4. On the client-side, make the AJAX call to that controller/action and do something with the response.